# How to configure C3P0 or BoneCP Datasources to withstand database failover/outage

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, c3p0, bonecp

I have a Spring/Hibernate based application which I need to modify to withstand a database outage up to 1 minute.
Instead of writing my own hack I took a look at C3P0 and BoneCP datasources to see if they could be configured for this purpose.
Unfortunently I was not able to get this to work for either of the datasources.
My test program terminated with various exceptions depending on which datasource was used:

**With the c3p0 datasource**

```
9558 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - connection exception: connection failure: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode; nested exception is      org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode
```

**With the c3p0 connectionprovider**

```
9341 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - connection exception: connection failure: java.io.EOFException
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Cannot open connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:627)
```

**With the BoneCP datasource**

```
12250 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - connection exception: connection failure: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:627)
```

**With the BoneCP connectionprovider**

```
19356 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - connection exception: connection failure: java.io.EOFException
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Cannot open connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:627)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:913)
    at my.db.failover.CustomerDao.list(CustomerDao.java:14)
```

The C3P0 documentation states that it can handle a situation like this while the BoneCP documentation don't mention this directly.

To test this I wrote a little program which reads a table from a HSQLDB server and sleeps for a second before repeating the process again.
It can be configured to run with following configurations: 
c3p0_datasource.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9002" />
    <property name="user" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="2" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="3" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="25" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3000" />
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="30" />
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1001" />
    <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="0" />
    <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="0" />
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="0" />
    <property name="automaticTestTable" value="C3P0_TEST" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" parent="abstractSessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

c3p0_connectionprovider.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" parent="abstractSessionFactory">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                . . .
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">25</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statement">0</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1;</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</prop>     
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

bonecp_datasource.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   <property name="driverClass" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
   <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9002" />
   <property name="username" value="sa"/>
   <property name="password" value=""/>
   <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60"/>
   <property name="idleMaxAge" value="240"/>
   <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="30"/>
   <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="10"/>
   <property name="partitionCount" value="3"/>
   <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"/>
   <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100"/>
   <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" parent="abstractSessionFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

bonecp_connectionprovider.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" parent="abstractSessionFactory">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.jolbox.bonecp.provider.BoneCPConnectionProvider</prop>
                . . .
                <prop key="bonecp.idleMaxAgeInMinutes">2</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes">3</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.partitionCount">3</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.acquireIncrement">10</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.maxConnectionsPerPartition">60</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.minConnectionsPerPartition">20</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.statementsCacheSize">50</prop>
                <prop key="bonecp.releaseHelperThreads">3</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Does anyone know if this could be done?

PS!
You can download the test project from [this link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4555647/DbFailoverTest.zip) if anyone needs to look deeper into this :)

Here are the steps to build and run the stuff.

```
1. Build the project with Maven:  
  mvn clean install package appassembler:assemble 
2. Set the start scripts as executable (Unix/linux)
  chmod +x target/appassembler/bin/*  
3. Run the DBServer 
  target/appassembler/bin/dbServer 
4. Run the test client from another shell 
  target/appassembler/bin/client
5. Select one of following configurations to use for the client 
    0 : c3p0_datasource.xml
    1 : c3p0_connectionprovider.xml
    2 : bonecp_datasource.xml
    3 : bonecp_connectionprovider.xml
6. Terminate the dbServer with ctrl c
7. Start it again and the client should survive the DB outage
```

But it does not :(

Answer (score 4):

c3p0 will recover from a database outage of arbitrary duration, as long as `breakOnAcquireFailure` is not set to `true`. however, that does not mean that clients will never see an Exception on acquire failure. by default, c3p0 will throw Exceptions to clients after a full round of acquisition attempts has failed, which will take 30030 ms (~30 secs) under your config. if you want c3p0 to continue trying to acquire Connections for longer before throwing Exceptions to clients, either set `acquireRetryAttempts` higher or `acquireRetryDelay` longer. the total length of a round of acquisition attempts is `acquireRetryAttempts * acquireRetryDelay`

if you want clients to wait indefinitely for recovery upon a database outage, set `acquireRetryAttempts` to 0. with this setting, when c3p0 cannot acquire a Connection, it will keep trying indefinitely every `acquireRetryDelay` milliseconds, and let clients hang until it succeeds or the sun burns out.

Please see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_recovery

p.s. the Exceptions you are providing are very superficial. you'll need to look into log files to see and provide better information about what's going on.